# Is there a solution to the extra padding added in IE 7/8 on input type=submit when a background image is used + other IE 7/8 oddities?

Tags: internet-explorer, form-submit, padding

I've been trying to figure out where I am getting this extra space between the border and the background image on my input[type=submit] in IE 7/8. It seems if I change the background to an actual image instead of just using color, IE adds this extra space?

Another oddity I found, is that if you click on one of the text inputs in the form, it adds 1px black "outline" around the submit button.

I have a demo page set up here - http://bit.ly/i3XC1y

Comment: links to non existent or expired pages is not very useful..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked on this some more and the best solution I've found that seems to render the input very similar across the following browsers, IE6 - IE8, FF3.5 and FF3.6, Chrome, Opera, and Safari was to wrap my submit input with a div.

Below is the mark-up I used.

HTML

```
<form method="get" action="">
    <input name="text1" type="text" class="text-input" />
    <input name="text2" type="text" class="text-input"/>
    <div class="submit-btn"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit-input-wrapped" /></div>
</form>
```

CSS

```
div.submit-btn{
    border:1px solid #000;
    width:70px;
}

div.submit-btn .submit-input-wrapped{
    background:url(big-btn.jpg);
    border:none;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    height:30px;
    line-height:30px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
    text-indent:0px;
    width:70px;
}

div.submit-btn .submit-input-wrapped:hover{
    background-position:0px -23px;
}
```

Like I said, this seems to work the best, it got rid of the extra white space padding in IE and hover outline when another input is focused in the same form as the submit input.

One small thing I did notice was the horizontal alignment of the text. By default, it seems the submit input centers the value text, yet I noticed some discrepancies between FF and the other browsers. Its not very noticeable, but If you set the text align to left on the submit input, you'll notice there is a little padding between the left border and the value text in FF. All other browsers the value text is flush with the left border when the text-align value is set to left.

Answer (score 5):

Here is simple soution for your problem. Just add a sinlge line to your class, and it's done, Here we go for the solution :

> ```
> .submit-btn{ overflow:visible }
> ```

Visit http://blog.10pixel.com/input-button-extra-width-in-ie-7-fix/ for more details.